# React - iterating through JSON object

Tags: json, reactjs

I am new to Javascripting and React JS coding. I have this JSON object-

```
var json1 = {"facilities":{"facility":[{"facilityCode":"J0LN","facilityId":"1","facilityName":"J0LN","npid":"1295718450","pid":"123457","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"K0NS","facilityId":"2","facilityName":"K0NS","npid":"9696969669","pid":"111111","providerState":"Alaska"},{"facilityCode":"J0LN1","facilityId":"3","facilityName":"J0LN1","npid":"111111111","pid":"221133","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"0987654321","facilityId":"4","facilityName":"0987654321","npid":"0987654321","pid":"235675","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"7776667676","facilityId":"5","facilityName":"7776667676","npid":"7776667676","pid":"236576","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"979797977","facilityId":"6","facilityName":"979797977","npid":"979797977","pid":"325347","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"9898989898","facilityId":"7","facilityName":"9898989898","npid":"9898989898","pid":"989898","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"121212","facilityId":"8","facilityName":"121212","npid":"1212120022","pid":"121212","providerState":"Connecticut"},{"facilityCode":"141414","facilityId":"9","facilityName":"141414","npid":"1414140022","pid":"141414","providerState":"Delaware"},{"facilityCode":"887766","facilityId":"10","facilityName":"887766","npid":"8877660022","pid":"887766","providerState":"Delaware"},{"facilityCode":"212121","facilityId":"11","facilityName":"OP-212121-OP","npid":"2121210022","pid":"212121","providerState":"Maryland"},{"facilityCode":"717171","facilityId":"12","facilityName":"IP-Qrtly-717171","npid":"7171710022","pid":"717174","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"RMC","facilityId":"13","facilityName":"RMC","npid":"1","pid":"676767","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"WCC","facilityId":"14","facilityName":"WCC","npid":"2","pid":"454676","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"FC","facilityId":"15","facilityName":"FN","npid":"1992813240","pid":"123456","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"VCC","facilityId":"16","facilityName":"VCC","npid":"1213121312","pid":"122312","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAA","facilityId":"17","facilityName":"AAAAA","npid":"3","pid":"112233","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAB","facilityId":"18","facilityName":"AAAAB","npid":"4","pid":"334455","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAC","facilityId":"19","facilityName":"AAAAC","npid":"5","pid":"556677","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAD","facilityId":"20","facilityName":"AAAAD","npid":"6","pid":"778899","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAE","facilityId":"21","facilityName":"AAAAE","npid":"7","pid":"616161","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAF","facilityId":"22","facilityName":"AAAAF","npid":"8","pid":"626262","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAG","facilityId":"23","facilityName":"AAAAG","npid":"9","pid":"717171","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAH","facilityId":"24","facilityName":"AAAAH","npid":"10","pid":"727272","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAI","facilityId":"25","facilityName":"AAAAI","npid":"11","pid":"757575","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAJ","facilityId":"26","facilityName":"AAAAJ","npid":"12","pid":"767676","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAK","facilityId":"27","facilityName":"AAAAK","npid":"13","pid":"818181","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAL","facilityId":"28","facilityName":"AAAAL","npid":"14","pid":"828282","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAM","facilityId":"29","facilityName":"AAAAM","npid":"15","pid":"858585","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAN","facilityId":"30","facilityName":"AAAAN","npid":"16","pid":"868686","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAO","facilityId":"31","facilityName":"AAAAO","npid":"17","pid":"919191","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAP","facilityId":"32","facilityName":"AAAAP","npid":"18","pid":"929292","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAQ","facilityId":"33","facilityName":"AAAAQ","npid":"19","pid":"959595","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"AAAAR","facilityId":"34","facilityName":"AAAAR","npid":"20","pid":"969696","providerState":"Alabama"},{"facilityCode":"UNIQUE","facilityId":"35","facilityName":"UNIQUE","npid":"21","pid":"123456","providerState":"Alabama"}]}};
```

I am setting the state of my data here and binding it (not sure why I am doing this, but I see everyone doing it as part of their ajax calls)

```
var stateSet = function(data) {         
    this.setState({data: json1});
};

stateSet.bind(this); // attempt to mock an AJAX call here, by assuming we have already obtained the JSON object.

return(
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Facility Code</th>
                <th>Facility ID</th>
                <th>Facility Name</th>
                <th>NPID</th>
                <th>PID</th>
                <th>Provider State</th>
            </tr>
            {
                this.state.data.map(function(facility, key) {
// I'm not sure if the control is entering this function, and I don't understand why
                    return (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{facility.facilityCode}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityId}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityName}</td>
                            <td>{facility.npid}</td>
                            <td>{facility.pid}</td>
                            <td>{facility.providerState}</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                })
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
);
```

As I've mentioned in the code as part of the comment, I don't think the control is entering `this.state.data.map(function(facility, key) {` function and I don't understand why.

Comment: where is your state = { data: {} }     ?

Comment: I'm trying to set it using `this.setState({data:json1})`

Comment: you should never call setState in render, from your question it seems like setState is called in render

Comment: Should be `this.state.data.facilities.facility.map(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not targeting the `facility` array correctly.

It should be `this.state.data.facilities.facility.map`, and you may also set your `json1` to `state` in your `constructor` directly like so

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    var json1 = {
      facilities: {
        facility: [
          {
            facilityCode: "J0LN",
            facilityId: "1",
            facilityName: "J0LN",
            npid: "1295718450",
            pid: "123457",
            providerState: "Alabama"
          } ....
        ]
      }
    };

    this.state = {
      data: json1
    };
  }
```

[Working Snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/p13z652mx)

Answer (score 2):

You path to array in incorrect, also add a check on availability of `this.state.data` so that it doesn't fail if `data` is not available,

```
{this.state.data && this.state.data.facilities.facility.map(function(facility, key) {}}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. I get `TypeError: this.state.data.facilities is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You re are use a map function on an object that has only on prop, this is not possible. The only prop the json object has is facilities

Comment: Check nrgwsth example

Answer (score 1):

```
var stateSet = function(data) {         
    this.setState({data: json1});
};
```

why are you using function(date), this is not needed. Just give function(), because i think the stateSet is firstly not called anywhere so it doesn t get triggerd and you re expecting a prop in that function.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it is clear that you are trying to access the **facility** array inside the facilities object.

You can achieve this as:

`this.state.data.facilities.facility.map((elementOffFacilityArray,index) => 
   { 
  // do whatever you would like to do with individual elements of the array.
   })`

But at the time when this map function will execute, it might be the case that this facility array may be empty which will result in error whic already has been pointed out by @nrgwsth. Thus, you will have to keep the check and the above expression for this case will become as :

```
{
  this.state.data &&
    this.state.data.facilities && 
     this.state.data.facilities.facility ?
      this.state.data.facilities.facility.map((elementOffFacilityArray,index) => 
        { 
          // do whatever you would like to do with individual elements of 
             the array.
        })
        :
        ''
}
```